# SOAP web service returning html code on iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, web-services, soap, ios10, afnetworking-3

I am trying to use the SOAp web service in my code and its not working as expected. The same code works fine prior to iOS 10.

Has anybody faced the same issue?

**My code looks like this:**

```
NSString *version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        NSString *msg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                       "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                       "<soap:Body>\n"
                       "<GetConfiguration xmlns=\"http://example.com/webservices/\">\n"
                       "<app_version>%@</app_version>\n"
                       "</GetConfiguration>\n"
                       "</soap:Body>\n"
                       "</soap:Envelope>\n",version];

        NSURL * getUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:GET_CONFIGURATION_URL];
        [Logger Log:GET_CONFIGURATION_URL];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:getUrl];
        NSString *msgLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[msg length]];


        [theRequest addValue:@"application/json;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [theRequest addValue:@"http://example.com/webservices/GetConfiguration" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:[msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];


        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];//I also used AFJSONResponseSerializer but no success.


        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);


            }
        }];
        [dataTask resume];
```

And I get the response embedded in `<html> ... </html`> which is in fact the code from server.

I am unable to get rid of this error.

**Edit, the response is as follows:**

```
<html>

    <head><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="/webservices/AppWebService.asmx?disco" />

    <style type="text/css">

        BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; }
        #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; }
        A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
        A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
        A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
        A:hover { color: cc3300; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
        P { color: #000000; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 12px; font-family: Verdana; }
        pre { background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; font-size: x-small; margin-top: -5px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; }
        td { color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; }
        h2 { font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #003366; margin-left: -15px; color: #003366; }
        h3 { font-size: 1.1em; color: #000000; margin-left: -15px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
        ul { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
        ol { margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
        li { margin-top: 10px; color: #000000; }
        font.value { color: darkblue; font: bold; }
        font.key { color: darkgreen; font: bold; }
        font.error { color: darkred; font: bold; }
        .heading1 { color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal; background-color: #003366; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: -30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 15px; width: 105%; }
        .button { background-color: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; border-top: #cccccc 1px solid; border-bottom: #666666 1px solid; border-left: #cccccc 1px solid; border-right: #666666 1px solid; }
        .frmheader { color: #000000; background: #dcdcdc; font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; font-weight: normal; border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; }
        .frmtext { font-family: Verdana; font-size: .7em; margin-top: 8px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 32px; }
        .frmInput { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em; }
        .intro { margin-left: -15px; }

    </style>

    <title>
    WebService Web Service
</title></head>

  <body>

    <div id="content">

      <p class="heading1">WebService</p><br>



      <span>
          <p class="intro">Click <a href="AppWebService.asmx">here</a> for a complete list of operations.</p>
          <h2>GetConfiguration</h2>
          <p class="intro"></p>

          <h3>Test</h3>

          The test form is only available for requests from the local machine.
                 <span>
              <h3>SOAP 1.1</h3>
              <p>The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response.  The <font class=value>placeholders</font> shown need to be replaced with actual values.</p>

              <pre>POST /webservices/AppWebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: MY_HOST_URL_HERE
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: <font class=value>length</font>
SOAPAction: "http://example.com/webservices/GetConfiguration"

&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
  &lt;soap:Body&gt;
    &lt;GetConfiguration xmlns="http://example.com/webservices/"&gt;
      &lt;app_version&gt;<font class=value>string</font>&lt;/app_version&gt;
    &lt;/GetConfiguration&gt;
  &lt;/soap:Body&gt;
&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;</pre>

              <pre>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: <font class=value>length</font>

&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
  &lt;soap:Body&gt;
    &lt;GetConfigurationResponse xmlns="http://example.com/webservices/"&gt;
      &lt;GetConfigurationResult&gt;<font class=value>string</font>&lt;/GetConfigurationResult&gt;
    &lt;/GetConfigurationResponse&gt;
  &lt;/soap:Body&gt;
&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;</pre>
          </span>

          <span>
              <h3>SOAP 1.2</h3>
              <p>The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response.  The <font class=value>placeholders</font> shown need to be replaced with actual values.</p>

              <pre>POST /webservices/AppWebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: MY_HOST_URL_HERE
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: <font class=value>length</font>

&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"&gt;
  &lt;soap12:Body&gt;
    &lt;GetConfiguration xmlns="http://example.com/webservices/"&gt;
      &lt;app_version&gt;<font class=value>string</font>&lt;/app_version&gt;
    &lt;/GetConfiguration&gt;
  &lt;/soap12:Body&gt;
&lt;/soap12:Envelope&gt;</pre>

              <pre>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: <font class=value>length</font>

&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"&gt;
  &lt;soap12:Body&gt;
    &lt;GetConfigurationResponse xmlns="http://example.com/webservices/"&gt;
      &lt;GetConfigurationResult&gt;<font class=value>string</font>&lt;/GetConfigurationResult&gt;
    &lt;/GetConfigurationResponse&gt;
  &lt;/soap12:Body&gt;
&lt;/soap12:Envelope&gt;</pre>
          </span>


      </span>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post that HTML response here ?

Comment: Try to get data with out using AFNetworking

Comment: @himanth I have already tried without AFNetworking. The response is same.

Comment: @CodeChanger The response is nothing but the backend coding.So I can't post it here. Just consider the scenario as I am not getting proper response from service.

Comment: ok so in this case there are many possible cases **1st.** is server is not able to understand your request and through some error or my be that server url not reachable **2nd.** your request not handle properly at backend and they gives wired error in HTML.

Comment: @CodeChanger But the same code is working fine on iOS versions prior to iOS 10. Then how's that possible?

Comment: strange thats why i am asking that HTML response so can get idea whats the error is there with iOS 10 ?

Comment: Hmm ok let me edit the response and I will put it here.

Comment: from above HTM i find this `The test form is only available for requests from the local machine.` so are you calling from local machine or through internet ???

Comment: I am calling via Internet

Comment: so check your server URL i think problem is there.

Comment: @CodeChanger No brother URL is correct. If that would have been the case then the API would have not worked on other versions.This problem is occurring only on iOS 10.